# How to make a UICollectionView fill vertical space before moving to next row

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I want to use a UICollectionView to create a layout that looks like this.

[image: desired flow]

However, the default flow layout lays things out like this instead.

[image: actual layout]

How should I go about trying to achieve my desired effect? Can UICollectionViewFlowLayout being configured to behave like this or should I look into creating a custom layout instead?

Comment: You need a custom layout for that.

Comment: As @rdelmar suggested, a collection view can have a maximum height and you cannot fit 2 cells inside a space of 1 even if there is space for it, as cells are being reused, 
For your desired layout you would have to make a custom layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom layout that should help you is available at the [GitHub](https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout)